# how to get multiple message from onMessage in GCMIntentService

Tags: android

Actually I want to get multiple text like icon URL and text message and also some other text message from server,but did not get any idea to do it.
here is my code which is,I am trying to do.

```
    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String messages = intent.getExtras().getString("price");
//  String message1 = intent.getExtras().getString("price1");//tried
    displayMessage(context, "server second message is " + messages);
    // notifies user
    generateNotification(context, messages);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to get the icon url, app icon will be used for notification

Comment: You might want to try using a JSON encoded string in the 'messages'

Comment: yes mach i want to get json code by which i can get multiple string.i don't know how to do it.can you help me??

Comment: i need other images and string which will decide that what to do next and want to get image url and text from server through gcm.